# If $A \subseteq B$, is it true that $C \cap A \subseteq C \cap B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \subseteq B \implies C \cap A \subseteq C \cap B$ ?

Let $x \in C \cap A \implies x \in C$ and $x \in A$ $\implies$ $x \in C$ and $x \in B$ $\implies x \in C \cap B$

is this valid?

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: Now it’s fine, though it would be easier to read with more words, and you could shorten it a little: if $x\in C\cap A$, then $x\in C$ and $x\in A\subseteq B$, so $x\in C\cap B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, since your definition of intersection isn't correct.

If $x \in C \cap A$, then $x \in C$ **and** $x \in A$. If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, so $x \in C$ and $x \in B$, so $x \in C \cap B$.